# getting rid of white space in List<string> that resides in Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, trim

I have a dictionary with a string as key and a List as value.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

So for each key there are several string values associated with the key.
The Problem is that the list values conytains some whitespace that I need to get rid of and what I do is passing the values of each list value to a different list using the trim() method and then after the loop assign it back to the original list.

```
List<string> lstNoWhite = new List<string>();
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < kvp.Value.Count; i++)
    {
        lstNoWhite.Add(kvp.Value[i].Trim());
    }
    kvp.Value = lstNoWhite;
}
```

I do however get the error...along the lines of that the list cannot be assigned to as it is read only.

Which is a better way of getting rid of the whitespace?

Comment: The error you get would be a compile-time error from the last line in the `foreach` block. Your `kvp` is a `KeyValuePair<,>`, and the property `Value` has a getter but no setter, so you can't assign to it. Instead you could say: `kvp.Value.Clear(); /* empties list */ kvp.Value.AddRange(lstNoWhite); /* adds many values to list */` Also consider if you need to reuse the same `lstNoWhite` for every `kvp` in `dict`, without even using `lstNoWhite.Clear()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
// source dictionary
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

// target dictionary
Dictionary<string, List<string>> target = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

// using LINQ extension methods
dict.ToList().ForEach(i =>
{
    List<string> temp = i.Value.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
    target.Add(i.Key, temp);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slightly modify your code to get rid of intermediate list:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < kvp.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                kvp.Value[i] = kvp.Value[i].Trim();
            }
        }
```

This will trim all whitespace in all strings from lists

Comment: Seems like the most elegant solution, and it doesn't require creating new `List<>` or `Dictionary<,>` along the way. Of course it assumes (as did the original code from the question) that no value in the dictionary is `null` (of type `List<string>`), and that no string in any of the lists is `null` (of type `string`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

// var --> Dictionary<string, List<string>>
var trimmedDict = dict.ToDictionary(
    keyValue => keyValue.Key, // The key
    keyValue => keyValue.Value.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList() // The value, trim all the strings in the value-list
);
```

Comment: Down voting without explaining always seem so meaningful. *sigh*